# Command failed: "C:\xampp\htdocs\cordova-test\node_modules\.bin\webpack.cmd"

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, npm, webpack

I'm beginner at Cordova. I've just started to learn it some days ago. When I try to build my Cordova app, I get this error:
`Error: Command failed: "C:\xampp\htdocs\cordova-test\node_modules\.bin\webpack.cmd"`.

How can I fix it? I found one solution of this problem (deleting of `package-lock.json` and then `npm install` again), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that removing my node_modules folder and my package.json.
Then -> npm init

and reinstall the packages that you need.